# Web API 2 return custom success / error object

Tags: asp.net-web-api, custom-error-handling

I am having a bit of issues with my Web API 2 project.

In order to connect to a mobile app client i will need to provide with custom success / error object in this way:

Products (GET)

- on Success 200: return a list with (ID, Name)
- on Error: return a custom object with (ErrorCode, ErrorDescription)

How can I do this in a nice way? 
Using *JsonResult* or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
public class CustomErrorObject
{
   public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
   public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}

public class HandleApiExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);

        HttpRequestMessage request = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Request;
        CustomErrorObject response = new CustomErrorObject();
        response.ErrorCode = actionExecutedContext.Exception.Data("Text");
        response.ErrorDescription = actionExecutedContext.Exception.Data("Detail");

        actionExecutedContext.Response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
    }
}
```

Then in the Global.asax add this line to the Application_Start event:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new HandleApiExceptionAttribute())
```

If you'd like to know more about exception handling in Web API: [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)